# Covariance of random variables and non-increasing function

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y] = f(Y)$$ almost-surely and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is non-increasing. Show that $Cov(X,Y)\leq 0$.
>
> Tip: Show that $Cov(X,Y) =  \mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-f(\mathbb{E}[Y]))(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])]$.

We know that
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]] = \mathbb{E}[f(Y)] \quad a.s.
$$
thus
\begin{align}
Cov(X,Y) &= \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]) \\
         &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]) \;| \; Y]] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X]) \;| \; Y](Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])] 
\end{align}
which follows from the fact that $(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])$ is $\sigma\langle Y\rangle$-measurable,
\begin{align}
&= \mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-\mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-\mathbb{E}[f(Y)])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])] \\
\end{align}

however this is where I get stuck. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142937/covariance-between-a-random-variable-and-a-decreasing-function-of-it-is-negative). OP has shown that if  $\text{E}[X|Y] = f(Y)$  then  $\text{cov}[X,Y] = \text{cov}[f(Y),Y]$. The answer to their question from there is explicitly given in the aforementioned post.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry for marking no in the duplicated disclaimer. Now I get it, I just need to add the other post rationale to the end of my solution. Thanks!