Proving Negative Covariance Between a Component of a Random Vector and the Reciprocal of Its Sum
I am working on a problem involving the covariance between a component of a random vector and the reciprocal of its sum. Specifically, let $X=(X_1,X_2,…,X_N)$ be a vector of non-negative, possibly dependent random variables, and let $Z=∑_i X_i$​. I am trying to prove that the covariance $cov(X_i, 1/Z)$ is negative for any $i$.
The intuition is that if $X_i$ increases then $Z$ decreases, but I'm not sure about the right approach to prove/disprove this. Does anyone have an idea? Is it even possible to say anything?
PS: A simple example using a Gaussian random vector $X$ seems to agree with the intuition (I used a covariance matrix that is unitary on the diagonal, and $0.5$ everywhere else).

Does this answer the question?  Covariance between a random variable and a decreasing function of it is negative?.

Hi, it seems that in the multivariate case the answer is different. See also the example from @Henry

Suppose $X=(X_1,X_2)$ is $(1,7)$ with probability $\frac12$ and is $(3,1)$ with probability $\frac12$.
Then $\frac1Z=\frac{1}{X_1+X_2}$ is $\frac18$ in the first case and $\frac14$ in the second case
making $\operatorname{cov}\left(X_1,\frac1Z\right)=\frac{1}{16}$, which is positive.
(This type of counter-example would not work if $X_1$ and $X_2$ were independent.)

Thanks this seems correct! Looking at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142937/covariance-between-a-random-variable-and-a-decreasing-function-of-it-is-negative it seems like in the multivariate case is not sufficient to have $\partial f(X)/ \partial X_i <0$, with $f(X)=1/(\sum_i X_i)$. I wonder if there is a sufficient condition to guarantee negative covariance.

@ZackFisher - Thank you
